# Right justify SVG icons

Tags: html, css, svg

I am using social media icons from: https://sharingbuttons.io/

How do I right justify all three icons?

HTML

```
<!-- Sharingbutton Facebook -->
<a class="resp-sharing-button__link" href="https://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="">
  <div class="resp-sharing-button resp-sharing-button--facebook resp-sharing-button--small"><div aria-hidden="true" class="resp-sharing-button__icon resp-sharing-button__icon--solid">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M18.77 7.46H14.5v-1.9c0-.9.6-1.1 1-1.1h3V.5h-4.33C10.24.5 9.5 3.44 9.5 5.32v2.15h-3v4h3v12h5v-12h3.85l.42-4z"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<!-- Sharingbutton Twitter -->
<a class="resp-sharing-button__link" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=Here%20is%20some%20text&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="">
  <div class="resp-sharing-button resp-sharing-button--twitter resp-sharing-button--small"><div aria-hidden="true" class="resp-sharing-button__icon resp-sharing-button__icon--solid">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M23.44 4.83c-.8.37-1.5.38-2.22.02.93-.56.98-.96 1.32-2.02-.88.52-1.86.9-2.9 1.1-.82-.88-2-1.43-3.3-1.43-2.5 0-4.55 2.04-4.55 4.54 0 .36.03.7.1 1.04-3.77-.2-7.12-2-9.36-4.75-.4.67-.6 1.45-.6 2.3 0 1.56.8 2.95 2 3.77-.74-.03-1.44-.23-2.05-.57v.06c0 2.2 1.56 4.03 3.64 4.44-.67.2-1.37.2-2.06.08.58 1.8 2.26 3.12 4.25 3.16C5.78 18.1 3.37 18.74 1 18.46c2 1.3 4.4 2.04 6.97 2.04 8.35 0 12.92-6.92 12.92-12.93 0-.2 0-.4-.02-.6.9-.63 1.96-1.22 2.56-2.14z"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<!-- Sharingbutton E-Mail -->
<a class="resp-sharing-button__link" href="mailto:?subject=Here%20is%20some%20text&amp;body=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com" target="_self" rel="noopener" aria-label="">
  <div class="resp-sharing-button resp-sharing-button--email resp-sharing-button--small"><div aria-hidden="true" class="resp-sharing-button__icon resp-sharing-button__icon--solid">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M22 4H2C.9 4 0 4.9 0 6v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h20c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V6c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zM7.25 14.43l-3.5 2c-.08.05-.17.07-.25.07-.17 0-.34-.1-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.55.18-.68l3.5-2c.24-.14.55-.06.68.18.14.24.06.55-.18.68zm4.75.07c-.1 0-.2-.03-.27-.08l-8.5-5.5c-.23-.15-.3-.46-.15-.7.15-.22.46-.3.7-.14L12 13.4l8.23-5.32c.23-.15.54-.08.7.15.14.23.07.54-.16.7l-8.5 5.5c-.08.04-.17.07-.27.07zm8.93 1.75c-.1.16-.26.25-.43.25-.08 0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-3.5-2c-.24-.13-.32-.44-.18-.68s.44-.32.68-.18l3.5 2c.24.13.32.44.18.68z"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.resp-sharing-button__link,
.resp-sharing-button__icon {
  display: inline-block
}

.resp-sharing-button__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0.5em
}

.resp-sharing-button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 25ms ease-out;
  padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

.resp-sharing-button__icon svg {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.4em;
  vertical-align: top
}

.resp-sharing-button--small svg {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle
}

/* Non solid icons get a stroke */
.resp-sharing-button__icon {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill: none
}

/* Solid icons get a fill */
.resp-sharing-button__icon--solid,
.resp-sharing-button__icon--solidcircle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: none
}

.resp-sharing-button--twitter {
  background-color: #55acee
}

.resp-sharing-button--twitter:hover {
  background-color: #2795e9
}

.resp-sharing-button--pinterest {
  background-color: #bd081c
}

.resp-sharing-button--pinterest:hover {
  background-color: #8c0615
}

.resp-sharing-button--facebook {
  background-color: #3b5998
}

.resp-sharing-button--facebook:hover {
  background-color: #2d4373
}

.resp-sharing-button--tumblr {
  background-color: #35465C
}

.resp-sharing-button--tumblr:hover {
  background-color: #222d3c
}

.resp-sharing-button--reddit {
  background-color: #5f99cf
}

.resp-sharing-button--reddit:hover {
  background-color: #3a80c1
}

.resp-sharing-button--google {
  background-color: #dd4b39
}

.resp-sharing-button--google:hover {
  background-color: #c23321
}

.resp-sharing-button--linkedin {
  background-color: #0077b5
}

.resp-sharing-button--linkedin:hover {
  background-color: #046293
}

.resp-sharing-button--email {
  background-color: #777
}

.resp-sharing-button--email:hover {
  background-color: #5e5e5e
}

.resp-sharing-button--xing {
  background-color: #1a7576
}

.resp-sharing-button--xing:hover {
  background-color: #114c4c
}

.resp-sharing-button--whatsapp {
  background-color: #25D366
}

.resp-sharing-button--whatsapp:hover {
  background-color: #1da851
}

.resp-sharing-button--hackernews {
background-color: #FF6600
}
.resp-sharing-button--hackernews:hover, .resp-sharing-button--hackernews:focus {   background-color: #FB6200 }

.resp-sharing-button--vk {
  background-color: #507299
}

.resp-sharing-button--vk:hover {
  background-color: #43648c
}

.resp-sharing-button--facebook {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  border-color: #3b5998;
}

.resp-sharing-button--facebook:hover,
.resp-sharing-button--facebook:active {
  background-color: #2d4373;
  border-color: #2d4373;
}

.resp-sharing-button--twitter {
  background-color: #55acee;
  border-color: #55acee;
}

.resp-sharing-button--twitter:hover,
.resp-sharing-button--twitter:active {
  background-color: #2795e9;
  border-color: #2795e9;
}

.resp-sharing-button--email {
  background-color: #777777;
  border-color: #777777;
}

.resp-sharing-button--email:hover,
.resp-sharing-button--email:active {
  background-color: #5e5e5e;
  border-color: #5e5e5e;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I created a `<div class="container">` and used `text-align:right`.

```css
.container{
text-align:right;
}

.resp-sharing-button__link,
.resp-sharing-button__icon {
  display: inline-block
}

.resp-sharing-button__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0.5em
}

.resp-sharing-button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 25ms ease-out;
  padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

.resp-sharing-button__icon svg {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.4em;
  vertical-align: top
}

.resp-sharing-button--small svg {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle
}

/* Non solid icons get a stroke */
.resp-sharing-button__icon {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill: none
}

/* Solid icons get a fill */
.resp-sharing-button__icon--solid,
.resp-sharing-button__icon--solidcircle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: none
}

.resp-sharing-button--twitter {
  background-color: #55acee
}

.resp-sharing-button--twitter:hover {
  background-color: #2795e9
}

.resp-sharing-button--pinterest {
  background-color: #bd081c
}

.resp-sharing-button--pinterest:hover {
  background-color: #8c0615
}

.resp-sharing-button--facebook {
  background-color: #3b5998
}

.resp-sharing-button--facebook:hover {
  background-color: #2d4373
}

.resp-sharing-button--tumblr {
  background-color: #35465C
}

.resp-sharing-button--tumblr:hover {
  background-color: #222d3c
}

.resp-sharing-button--reddit {
  background-color: #5f99cf
}

.resp-sharing-button--reddit:hover {
  background-color: #3a80c1
}

.resp-sharing-button--google {
  background-color: #dd4b39
}

.resp-sharing-button--google:hover {
  background-color: #c23321
}

.resp-sharing-button--linkedin {
  background-color: #0077b5
}

.resp-sharing-button--linkedin:hover {
  background-color: #046293
}

.resp-sharing-button--email {
  background-color: #777
}

.resp-sharing-button--email:hover {
  background-color: #5e5e5e
}

.resp-sharing-button--xing {
  background-color: #1a7576
}

.resp-sharing-button--xing:hover {
  background-color: #114c4c
}

.resp-sharing-button--whatsapp {
  background-color: #25D366
}

.resp-sharing-button--whatsapp:hover {
  background-color: #1da851
}

.resp-sharing-button--hackernews {
background-color: #FF6600
}
.resp-sharing-button--hackernews:hover, .resp-sharing-button--hackernews:focus {   background-color: #FB6200 }

.resp-sharing-button--vk {
  background-color: #507299
}

.resp-sharing-button--vk:hover {
  background-color: #43648c
}

.resp-sharing-button--facebook {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  border-color: #3b5998;
}

.resp-sharing-button--facebook:hover,
.resp-sharing-button--facebook:active {
  background-color: #2d4373;
  border-color: #2d4373;
}

.resp-sharing-button--twitter {
  background-color: #55acee;
  border-color: #55acee;
}

.resp-sharing-button--twitter:hover,
.resp-sharing-button--twitter:active {
  background-color: #2795e9;
  border-color: #2795e9;
}

.resp-sharing-button--email {
  background-color: #777777;
  border-color: #777777;
}

.resp-sharing-button--email:hover,
.resp-sharing-button--email:active {
  background-color: #5e5e5e;
  border-color: #5e5e5e;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<!-- Sharingbutton Facebook -->
<a class="resp-sharing-button__link" href="https://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="">
  <div class="resp-sharing-button resp-sharing-button--facebook resp-sharing-button--small"><div aria-hidden="true" class="resp-sharing-button__icon resp-sharing-button__icon--solid">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M18.77 7.46H14.5v-1.9c0-.9.6-1.1 1-1.1h3V.5h-4.33C10.24.5 9.5 3.44 9.5 5.32v2.15h-3v4h3v12h5v-12h3.85l.42-4z"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<!-- Sharingbutton Twitter -->
<a class="resp-sharing-button__link" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=Here%20is%20some%20text&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="">
  <div class="resp-sharing-button resp-sharing-button--twitter resp-sharing-button--small"><div aria-hidden="true" class="resp-sharing-button__icon resp-sharing-button__icon--solid">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M23.44 4.83c-.8.37-1.5.38-2.22.02.93-.56.98-.96 1.32-2.02-.88.52-1.86.9-2.9 1.1-.82-.88-2-1.43-3.3-1.43-2.5 0-4.55 2.04-4.55 4.54 0 .36.03.7.1 1.04-3.77-.2-7.12-2-9.36-4.75-.4.67-.6 1.45-.6 2.3 0 1.56.8 2.95 2 3.77-.74-.03-1.44-.23-2.05-.57v.06c0 2.2 1.56 4.03 3.64 4.44-.67.2-1.37.2-2.06.08.58 1.8 2.26 3.12 4.25 3.16C5.78 18.1 3.37 18.74 1 18.46c2 1.3 4.4 2.04 6.97 2.04 8.35 0 12.92-6.92 12.92-12.93 0-.2 0-.4-.02-.6.9-.63 1.96-1.22 2.56-2.14z"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<!-- Sharingbutton E-Mail -->
<a class="resp-sharing-button__link" href="mailto:?subject=Here%20is%20some%20text&amp;body=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com" target="_self" rel="noopener" aria-label="">
  <div class="resp-sharing-button resp-sharing-button--email resp-sharing-button--small"><div aria-hidden="true" class="resp-sharing-button__icon resp-sharing-button__icon--solid">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M22 4H2C.9 4 0 4.9 0 6v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h20c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V6c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zM7.25 14.43l-3.5 2c-.08.05-.17.07-.25.07-.17 0-.34-.1-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.55.18-.68l3.5-2c.24-.14.55-.06.68.18.14.24.06.55-.18.68zm4.75.07c-.1 0-.2-.03-.27-.08l-8.5-5.5c-.23-.15-.3-.46-.15-.7.15-.22.46-.3.7-.14L12 13.4l8.23-5.32c.23-.15.54-.08.7.15.14.23.07.54-.16.7l-8.5 5.5c-.08.04-.17.07-.27.07zm8.93 1.75c-.1.16-.26.25-.43.25-.08 0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-3.5-2c-.24-.13-.32-.44-.18-.68s.44-.32.68-.18l3.5 2c.24.13.32.44.18.68z"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
</div>
```